# Sending a mail after creating of an entity | Symfony2 Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, events, sonata

I'd like to create a listener which is supposed to send an email after the creation of an entity.

I am using Sonata Admin Bundle, and I don't quite know what event is associated to the creation of an entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register Event Listener for Doctrine `postFlush` event.

Example listener:

```
class PostFlushExampleListener
{
    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Service registration in Symfony:

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: PostFlushExampleListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
```

Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Doctrine documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events

Comment: Thanks , I found my answer here http://culttt.com/2014/08/04/understanding-doctrine-2-lifecycle-events/#Lifecycle Event Listeners